# Index was outside the bounds of the array occurs on array initialization?

Tags: c#, .net

My program has been working fine for 2 months. But we received this exception today.

The program is multi-thread program. But only one thread use this class.

It is release mode, without Visual Studio.

The exception throws at this line:

```
int[] list = new int[count]; //Count = 52
```

The function is:

```
private static readonly Random _rand = new Random();
public static int[] GetList(int count)
    {
        int[] list = new int[count]; // this is line 21
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list[i] = i;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < count * count; i++)
        {
            int i1 = _rand.Next(count);
            int i2 = _rand.Next(count);

            if (i1 == i2) continue;

            //swap values
            list[i1] ^= list[i2];
            list[i2] ^= list[i1];
            list[i1] ^= list[i2];
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Part of the log is:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>
> at iCulture.GameFramework.Util.RandomList.GetList(Int32 count) in C:\Rm716b\texasgame\TexasHoldem\trunk\iCulture.GameFramework\Util\RandomList.cs:line 21
>
> at iCulture.Texas.Cards..ctor() in C:\Rm716b\texasgame\TexasHoldem\trunk\iCulture.Texas\Cards.cs:line 18
>
> at iCulture.Texas.TexasGame..ctor(Player[] ParticipatePlayers, Int32 SmallBindAmount, Int32 SmallBlindPosition) in C:\Rm716b\texasgame\TexasHoldem\trunk\iCulture.Texas\TexasGame.cs:line 46

I have tried decompiling the DLL, but the code logic remains the same as the original source code.

It is possible hardware error cause this problem? Because it DOES NOT reappear since then.

Comment: Please don't use XOR to implement a swap in a managed language.  We're not limited to 64K of RAM with 32K bank sizes anymore.

Comment: I have reread the question and withdrew my original erroneous answer (too many "i"s got me confused). You state that the exception occurs on the first line of code, in the method, but it isn't possible to get that exception on that line of code, even if out of memory. I think that there is more or different code that isn't being shown; can you please re-check your code and update your question with information on where the error is actually occurring.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the actual exception you are seeing, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

The method works fine. I ran it 10000 times, and no errors.

The only thing that I can think of is if you are using this in a multi-threaded application. The `Random` class is not thread safe, so threads using the same instance could mess up its internal values. In that case each thread should have its own instance of the random generator, and you should send that in as a parameter to the method.

Your method of shuffling the items isn't very efficient. You should use the [Fisher.Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algoritm instead, which is an O(n) operation instead of O(n*n). Also, your method has a slight bias towards the original order, while this has no bias:

```
public static int[] GetList(int count) {
  int[] list = new int[count];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    list[i] = i;
    // swap the item with any previous item, or itself
    int swap = _rand.Next(i + 1);
    if (swap != i) {
      int temp = list[i];
      list[i] = list[swap];
      list[swap] = temp;
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and received no exceptions or errors.

This narrows it down to your `_rand` declaration.  Are you specifying a seed value?  If so, that could be throwing off your index if it is greater than `count`.

You should be declaring the `_rand` class field something like this:

```
static Random _rand = new Random();
```

But the code you listed is working code.

Step through your code and see what `_rand.Next(count)` returns.  I guarantee you it's not a usable index for your array.

Comment: No idea. It works fine for 2 months. But received this exception today.

Comment: @Neio ZHOU, it doesn't make sense for it to fail on that line, in any case.  I suggest you double check that the source matches the binary you're running; you can wind up with strange failures in cases where you're debugging one version of code with a different version of source.

Comment: I'm with @DanBryant on this one.  This sounds like a non-application error.  If you are throwing your exception upon declaration of your array you are having some underlying issues.  Run the application on another machine (working machine) and you won't have this problem.  Guaranteed.

Comment: I also ran the code for a count of 10 million and never got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an IndexOutOfBoundsException cannot be thrown on an array that hasn't been declared yet.

The error is happening in release mode without the debugger attached.  This is good to know.  Keep in mind that there are major optimizations done by Visual Studio when your code is compiled in release *and* not attached to a debugger.  This leads me to my main point.

### YOU ARE BEING MISLED BY THE STACK TRACE

I confirmed this myself, by purposely trying to access an element outside of the array.  The stack trace said the error happened on line 36, which for me is: `return list;`  The actual error that I caused, was inserted on line 31.

I doubt the stack trace isn't lying about what function the exception is happening, though.  But I would say that the code throwing the exception is probably not the code you see in Visual Studio.

1. Does the issue happen when you run it in Release mode with the debugger attached?
2. Open the code in a decompiler, like [this one](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).  If you browsed to the method you have above, does the source code match (more or less, a decompiler isn't perfect).

EDIT:

So the code seems to be the same.  Either way, the error that you are getting is not happening at the line the stack trace is telling you.  There's nothing I can do to help you at this point, since I don't have access to the offending binary.

My suggestion:  When the application crashes, use Task Manager to save a dump of the program's memory.  (Alternatively, you can use [AdPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) or [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900), to do it automatically when it crashes).  Use WinDbg to open the dump and view the memory, stack trace, and even the jitted methods to try and determine where it actually happened.

Other than that, there's not much you can get from anyone else here on StackOverflow.  Bugs like this are a pain, and unfortunately happen every once and a while.

Comment: @NeioZHOU - np, I thought that might have been the case.  Can you reproduce the exception again, or was it only happening the one time?

Comment: Thank you. I have try the decompiler, but the source code matches. I doubt if it is caused by hardware error, since this program performs OK for 2 months.

Comment: @NeioZHOU - You need to figure out where the error is actually happening.  Does the error happen when you run it in release with the debugger attached? or are you trying to debug a certain build?

Comment: It is release mode program. No debugger attached.

Comment: @NeioZHOU - *CAN* you run it with a debugger attached?  If you can't, then you will need to get a memory dump of your application (can get it via Task Manager) and debug the dump via WinDbg and the SOS extension.  It's out of the scope of this answer, but google them for information about it.

Comment: The program runs for many days and just crash there, the log shows that exception. I have tried the JustDecompile to decompile the problem dll.

Answer (score -1):

`list[i1] ^= list[i2];
            list[i2] ^= list[i1];
            list[i1] ^= list[i2];`
these lines of codes point to values that might be outside the declaration limit.
The code looks faulty ... what are you trying to achieve ?